# Getting Rid of Grey Font and Text-box Border in Contact Form

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, contacts

Making a basic contact form for a website. Using template from [here](https://www.behance.net/gallery/8551387/JavaScript-Contact-Form-All-code-no-images-used)

Using this jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/q7mzbpof/

I was wondering how to get rid of the grey text and blue block bar that surrounds it when you click to enter something. If there is a better option that I haven't found for contact form templates I'm happy to take them and run with them. This was the first one I was able to find that would seem simple enough to work.

```
function kaderValidation()
{
var name1 = document.registration.fname;
var name2 = document.registration.lname;
var addy = document.registration.address;
var mnum = document.registration.Mnumber;
var mailat = document.registration.email;

 if(fname_validation(name1))
{
if(lname_validation(name2))
{
if(alphanumeric(addy))
{ 
if(nums(mnum))
{
if(ValidateEmail(mailat))
{
if(validsex(umsex,ufsex))
{
}
} 
}
} 
}
}
return false;
} function fname_validation(name1)
{
var name1_len = name1.value.length;
if (name1_len == 0 )
{
alert("Please enter your first name");
name1.focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}
function lname_validation(name2)
{
var name2_len = name2.value.length;
if (name2_len == 0 )
{
alert("Please enter your last name");
name2.focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}
function alphanumeric(addy)
{ 
var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
if(addy.value.match(letters))
{
return true;
}
else
{
alert('Please enter the adress in format Countrty-City-Streetnumber without spaces');
addy.focus();
return false;
}
}
function nums(mnum)
{ 
var digits = /^[0-9]+$/;
if(mnum.value.match(digits))
{
return true;
}
else
{
alert('Please enter your Mobile number');
mnum.focus();
return false;
}
}
function ValidateEmail(mailat)
{
var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
if(mailat.value.match(mailformat))
{
return true;
}
else
{
alert("Please enter a valid email address");
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against doing these for sake of accessibility, but nonetheless you can accomplish this with some simple CSS.

```
input:focus {
  outline: none; /* gets rid of the blue outline on focus */
}

input:focus::-moz-input-placeholder {
    opacity: 0; /* hides the gray plceholder text in firefox */
}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    opacity: 0; /* hides the gray plceholder text in Chrome/Safari */
}
```

Comment: Why would you advise against? I'm not sure I follow?

Comment: Really more talking about getting rid of the outline–it's a cue to users, especially those that are physically impaired, that they're currently editing that particular field.

Comment: Oh, I see. I've learned a bit about that, but I thought that generally the UX would be to make that blue outline only appear when tab is pressed, instead of just clicked on by a regular mouse. Is the new trend to it always be bordered coming around? 

I just thought it didn't look that great with the curved border. Perhaps there is an easy CSS way to remake the box borders into an actual box so the outline would match?

Comment: I can definitely agree with you that it looks better without :) there is a neat article that talks about customizing the border you may find useful https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/glowing-blue-input-highlights/